# Sunrise and Sunset time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project that notifies the users when certain activities related to light are triggered. I've done the part related to light. Hence, I need to find an effective way to retrieve sunrise and sunset time in python, since the whole script is written in python. I know there are several libraries out there for other languages, I wonder what the most convenient way is to do this in python.

It will seem pretty much like this, I suppose:

```
if(sunrise<T<sunset) and (light<threshold):
    notifyUser()
```

I'd appreciate any help here, have a good one.

Comment: Note that `;` is superfluous, and it would be better written `if (sunrise < T < sunset) and (light < threshold):`

Comment: True dat. I just wanted to give an idea about the pseudocode I'm trying to write there. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have compared few packages ([suntime](https://pypi.org/project/suntime/), [suntimes](https://pypi.org/project/suntimes/), [sunriset](https://pypi.org/project/sunriset/), [astral](https://pypi.org/project/astral/)) and times sunrise and sunset times returned by them. All of them return local time but you can easily get UTC time as well.
This is the result:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pytz
import time
from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException
from suntimes import SunTimes
import sunriset
import astral, astral.sun

latitude = 52.0691667
longitude = 19.4805556
altitude = 0
tz_poland = pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')
tz_name = 'Europe/Warsaw'
for_date = date(2021, 4, 6)
print('====== suntime ======')
abd = for_date
sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()
print(today_sr.astimezone(tz_poland))
print(today_ss.astimezone(tz_poland))
print('====== suntimes ======')
sun2 = SunTimes(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude, altitude=altitude)
day = datetime(for_date.year, for_date.month, for_date.day)
print(sun2.risewhere(day, tz_name))
print(sun2.setwhere(day, tz_name))
print('====== sunriset ======')
local = datetime.now()
utc = datetime.utcnow()
local_tz = float(((local - utc).days * 86400 + round((local - utc).seconds, -1))/3600)
number_of_years = 1
start_date = for_date
df = sunriset.to_pandas(start_date, latitude, longitude, 2, number_of_years)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Sunrise'])
    print(row['Sunset'])
    break
print('====== astral ======')
l = astral.LocationInfo('Custom Name', 'My Region', tz_name, latitude, longitude)
s = astral.sun.sun(l.observer, date=for_date)
print(s['sunrise'].astimezone(tz_poland))
print(s['sunset'].astimezone(tz_poland))
```

And the return:

```
====== suntime ======
2021-04-06 06:05:00+02:00
2021-04-06 19:16:00+02:00
====== suntimes ======
2021-04-06 06:04:34.000553+02:00
2021-04-06 19:17:16.000613+02:00
====== sunriset ======
0 days 06:02:52.093465
0 days 19:16:49.892350
====== astral ======
2021-04-06 06:03:39.792229+02:00
2021-04-06 19:17:01.188463+02:00
```

Please note only suntimes package support altitude.

Comment: Anyone want to add `%%timeit` benchmark for processing multiple datetime data?

Comment: Benchmark done on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70186517/11671779)

Answer (score 27):

Check out [astral](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astral/1.2). Here's a slightly modified [example from their docs](https://astral.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sun):

```
>>> from astral import Astral
>>> city_name = 'London'
>>> a = Astral()
>>> a.solar_depression = 'civil'
>>> city = a[city_name]
>>> sun = city.sun(date=datetime.date(2009, 4, 22), local=True)

>>> if (sun['sunrise'] < T < sun['sunset']) and (light < threshold):
>>>    notifyUser()
```

If you use something like this example, please remember to change the `city_name` and date provided to `city.sun`.

Comment: Well, in which format does Astral return those times? For example, after defining:
             
            now = datetime.datetime.now();   
            
Can I use

            if (sun['sunrise'] < now < sun['sunset']) and (light < threshold):
                notifyUser()

Comment: This uses a prescribed date. How if the date is taken from a DateTime index of a time series?

Answer (score 15):

You can also try with [suntime](https://github.com/SatAgro/suntime). An example from their doc below:

```
import datetime
from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException

latitude = 51.21
longitude = 21.01

sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)

# Get today's sunrise and sunset in UTC
today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()
print('Today at Warsaw the sun raised at {} and get down at {} UTC'.
      format(today_sr.strftime('%H:%M'), today_ss.strftime('%H:%M')))

# On a special date in your machine's local time zone
abd = datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)
abd_sr = sun.get_local_sunrise_time(abd)
abd_ss = sun.get_local_sunset_time(abd)
print('On {} the sun at Warsaw raised at {} and get down at {}.'.
      format(abd, abd_sr.strftime('%H:%M'), abd_ss.strftime('%H:%M')))
```

Answer (score 11):

The `Astral` package example above appears to be dated.

Below is an example for `Astral v2.2` for the San Jose, CA airport location.

First, set up the observer's location:

```py
from astral import LocationInfo
loc = LocationInfo(name='SJC', region='CA, USA', timezone='America/Los_Angeles',
                   latitude=37.3713439, longitude=-121.944675)
print(loc)
# LocationInfo(name='SJC', region='CA, USA', timezone='America/Los_Angeles',
#   latitude=37.3713439, longitude=-121.944675)
print(loc.observer)
# Observer(latitude=37.3713439, longitude=-121.944675, elevation=0.0)
```

Note:

- Only the latitude, longitude, and timezone are important.
- The name and region are just labels.

Next, calculate the sun's info for that observer on the desired date (e.g., 2021-01-15 below):

```py
import datetime
from astral.sun import sun
s = sun(loc.observer, date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 15), tzinfo=loc.timezone)
for key in ['dawn', 'dusk', 'noon', 'sunrise', 'sunset']:
    print(f'{key:10s}:', s[key])
```

Output:

```
dawn      : 2021-01-15 06:52:04.342105-08:00
dusk      : 2021-01-15 17:42:59.471441-08:00
noon      : 2021-01-15 12:17:05-08:00
sunrise   : 2021-01-15 07:21:04.877697-08:00
sunset    : 2021-01-15 17:13:58.467348-08:00
```

Notes:

- If the timezone is not specified, it defaults to UTC.
- Noon is solar noon -- the time when the sun crosses the meridian at the observer's location.
- [Astral](https://astral.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an implementation of the [Excel sheets](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/calcdetails.html) published by the NOAA.

Answer (score 3):

Further improving @Wojciech Jakubas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66973947/11671779), this is the benchmark (ommitting timezone):

```py
# boilerplate
from datetime import date, datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pytz
import time
from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException
from suntimes import SunTimes
import sunriset
import astral, astral.sun

latitude = 6.2088
longitude = 106.8456
altitude = 0
tz_name = 'Asia/Jakarta'
for_date = date(2021, 4, 6)
```

```py
%%timeit
# print('====== suntime ======')
sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time(for_date)
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time(for_date)
# 20.3 µs ± 90.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
# print('====== suntimes ======')
sun2 = SunTimes(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude, altitude=altitude)
today_sr = sun2.riseutc(for_date)
today_ss = sun2.setutc(for_date)
# 83 µs ± 261 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
# print('====== sunriset ======')
df = sunriset.to_pandas(for_date, latitude, longitude, 0, 1)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    today_sr = row['Sunrise']
    today_ss = row['Sunset']
    break
# 28.7 ms ± 126 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
# print('====== astral ======')
l = astral.LocationInfo('Custom Name', 'My Region', tz_name, latitude, longitude)
today_sr = astral.sun.sunrise(l.observer, date=for_date)
today_ss = astral.sun.sunset(l.observer, date=for_date)
# 64.3 µs ± 292 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

To convert into local `time zone` (UTC+X), use:

```py
# with known region name
tz_name = 'Asia/Jakarta'
tz = pytz.timezone(tz_name)
today_sr.astimezone(tz)

# with known time different
time_different = 7
tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=time_different))
today_sr.astimezone(tz)
```

Conclusion:

1. Use `suntime` (Be aware that it use LGPL [LICENSE](https://github.com/SatAgro/suntime/blob/master/LICENSE)).
2. If you really need one year data and do not care with speed, try `sunriset` since it spout one year period.
3. `sunriset` need to be edited manually from the source code to solve only single time
4. `sunriset` output is in `timedelta`, thus can't be converted using `.astimezone` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using the [`skyfield`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) library. Here's a short example using the current version (`1.39`), adapted from [the documentation](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/almanac.html#sunrise-and-sunset):

```py
from skyfield import almanac, api

ts = api.load.timescale()
eph = api.load('de421.bsp')

# Location
bluffton = api.wgs84.latlon(+40.8939, -83.8917)

# Times between which to look for sunrises and sunsets
t0 = ts.utc(2018, 9, 12, 4)
t1 = ts.utc(2018, 9, 13, 4)

times, is_sunrise = almanac.find_discrete(t0, t1, almanac.sunrise_sunset(eph, bluffton))
```

`time` will contain the times of sunrises/sunsets between `t0` and `t1`, and the corresponding value in `is_sunrise` will be 1 if it's a sunrise and 0 for a sunset.